# Pass one queryset as parameter for exclude() in django

Tags: django

I have the following three models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Task(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class StudentTask(models.Model):
     student=models.ForeignKey(Student)
     task=models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

Now what I want is to show the list of tasks he is assigned to and the list of activities that he is not taking:

```
         my_tasks=StudentTask.objects.annotate(act_id=F('id'),act_name=F('task__name')).values('act_id','act_name').filter(student_id=id)

 tasks=Task.objects.exclude(id__in=my_tasks).values('id','name')
```

Which gives the error "Cannot use multi-field values as a filter value.". I googled and realized annotate got something to do with the error (but i didnt yet try without it).

Is it even worth trying to use my_tasks given any given student cant have more than three tasks? The following query works fine:

```
  tasks=Task.objects.exclude(id__in=StudentTask.objects.filter(student_id=id).values('task_id')
```

But it is querying the same thing twice. What is the proper way to do this, considering the first query will fail as it is?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is because in the first query, you are returning a dict which is populated by two attributes: act_id and act_name. And then you are using it in the exclude() filter in the second query. Try this:

```
my_tasks=StudentTask.objects.annotate(act_id=F('id'),act_name=F('task__name')).values('act_id','act_name').filter(student_id=id)

my_task_ids = [d['act_id'] for d in my_tasks]

tasks=Task.objects.exclude(id__in=my_task_ids).values('id','name')
```